# Modifying Devise RegistrationsController edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I currently have users editing their profile on `localhost:3000/en/users/edit?`
As they edit their profile they might need to add a company (`Entreprise`).

So I modify the edit page to receive a modal which is the `entreprise/new.html.erb`.

I think now i need to pass `@entreprise = current_user.entreprises.build` to the Registration controller (which is the one controlling the `user/edit.html.erb` page.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
 def edit
    super
    @entreprise = current_user.entreprises.build
  end

...
end
```

below I listed all the params for `Entreprise.new`

I have the following in my routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", confirmations: "confirmations", omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}, skip: :omniauth_callbacks
devise_scope :user do
  get "settings", to: "devise/registrations#edit"
end
```

When I load the edit page and call the modal, the page loads empty. I can see the console processing the following :

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
.......
  Rendering registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
.....
  Rendered registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (925.5ms)
.......
Processing by EntreprisesController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
 ......
  Rendering entreprises/new.html.erb within layouts/application
   ....

  Rendered entreprises/_form.html.erb (81.2ms)
  Rendered entreprises/new.html.erb within layouts/application (124.4ms)
```

But the modal does not open at all. When checking in the inspector, there is no information in the modal. The is no error records

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to assign your `@enterprise` variable before your `super` call (which calls `render :edit`), because when you render your view, the `@enterprise` variable is not actually assigned yet.

Comment: I don think this is where the problem is, because we see logs saying that the form was rendered. And since we are calling EntrepriseController#new, we actually should not need to call a build method again.

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that the components of the form are being called. 
What was missing here, `was new.js.erb` file. 
Inside which I added: `$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'entreprises/form' %>")`.
Now the form loads properly. next step is to get to save records in the entreprise model and it is all set.